# cargo and cross compilation of the same code result with different binaries (different hash)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Using the [cross crate](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross/) I compiled using this line:
`cross build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release`
and using cargo I compiled the same source:
`cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release`

The resulting binaries have different hashes and I was wondering why:

```
~/p/benchpress on  master is  v0.1.0 via  v1.44.1 on ☁️  eu-central-1
❯ sha256sum ./target/release/benchpress
a08a616388d8e3f1aaeb0df1b5ed2246daec66001a53bd34514794c266464a37  ./target/release/benchpress

~/p/benchpress on  master is  v0.1.0 via  v1.44.1 on ☁️  eu-central-1
❯ sha256sum ./target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/benchpress
ef08deb5b7bb0e75c9828ef93c5acd46cdb14267d95cd53f1eb6305887f30bde  ./target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/benchpress
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know that rust builds are guaranteed to be reproducible, but either way you may [want to inspect at the results](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/testing-out-reproducible-builds/9758) to see what varies, and possibly report the issue against either cross or rust itself? Don't see how anyone could help you if you don't provide, well, a reproduction case.

Comment: I guess the binaries are the same, but may differ in meta (e.g. build timestamps or some similar information).